# Display charts dynamically from dataTable

Tags: javascript, xhtml, amcharts

I want to display a chart using `Amcharts`, I have a  dataTable using `count/groupBy` from the data base. Now, I want to display the chart dynamically ,  I want to iterate the dataTable and make the first and the second column  in the  `chartData` array consecutively.
This is my dataTable:
[image]

Stat.xhtml

```
<h:form id="ff">
<rich:dataTable id="tablereparation"  value="#{stat.results}" var="rep">
<h:column headerClass="headerleftfacet">
<h:outputText id="np"  value="#{rep[0]}" /></h:column>
<h:column headerClass="headermiddlefacet">
<h:outputText id="nbpanne" value="#{rep[1]}" />
</h:column>
</rich:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

test.js

```
var chart;
var legend;
//my attempt
var table = document.getElementById('ff:tablereparation');
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");

    for (var j = 0; j <= 0; j++) {
        var cell = cells[j];
      alert(cells.innerHtml);
    }

}

var chartData = [{
    panne: ?,
    percpangrave: ?
}];


chart = new AmCharts.AmPieChart();
chart.dataProvider = chartData;
chart.titleField = "panne";
chart.valueField = "percpangrave";
chart.outlineColor = "#FFFFFF";
chart.outlineAlpha = 0.8;
chart.outlineThickness = 2;

legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
legend.position = "bottom";
legend.align = "center";
legend.markerType = "square";
legend.valueText = "";
chart.addLegend(legend);

chart.write("chartdiv1");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing anything about that kind of dataTable HTML, your JavaScript for reading the cell information doesn't look correct. You can get at the row's cells directly from the rows variable since each `<tr>` contains an associated `cells`  array  and just pull the innerHTML value out of them and dynamically populate the array. Here's an example below, which also demonstrates a quicker way to get at the rows through [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll):

```js
var chart;
var legend;
//var table = document.getElementById('ff:tablereparation');
//var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");
//shorter way of doing this: 
var rows = document.querySelectorAll("#ff\\:tablereparation tr"); //note double slash to escape the colon as a literal character since it's a selector in css
var chartData = [];

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  chartData.push({
    panne: rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML,
    percpangrave: rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML
  });
}


chart = new AmCharts.AmPieChart();
chart.dataProvider = chartData;
chart.titleField = "panne";
chart.valueField = "percpangrave";
chart.outlineColor = "#FFFFFF";
chart.outlineAlpha = 0.8;
chart.outlineThickness = 2;

legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
legend.position = "bottom";
legend.align = "center";
legend.markerType = "square";
legend.valueText = "";
chart.addLegend(legend);

chart.write("chartdiv1");
```

```css
#chartdiv1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="ff:tablereparation">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Title 1</td>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Title 2</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Title 3</td>
      <td>60</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Title 4</td>
      <td>40</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id="chartdiv1"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when I try to display `rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML`, I had this result `<span id="ff:tablereparation:0:np">Panne grave</span>`, I want just the value, in this case `Panne grave`

Comment: just I replaced `innerHtml` by `textContent` and It works